# I stumbled across an identity and I don't know to prove it

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I stumbled across this apparent identity:
$$aa^{-1}_{b}+bb^{-1}_{a}-1=ab$$
where
$$
a,b\in \mathbb{N/\{0\}} \\ 
gcd(a,b)=1 \\ 
(a^{-1}_{b})\equiv a^{\phi(b)-1} \mod b \\ 
(b^{-1}_{a})\equiv b^{\phi(a)-1} \mod a \\
$$
Pretty much $a^{-1}_{b}$ and $b^{-1}_{a}$ are multiplicative inverses and I chose for simplicity that a and b are coprime. If I run values in python it seems to be true. What I've done so far is prove that the lhs is a multiple of the rhs:
$$
a^{-1}_{b} = a^{\phi(b)-1} \\
b^{-1}_{a} = b^{\phi(a)-1} \\
E = aa^{-1}_{b}+bb^{-1}_{a}-1=a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}-1 \\
E \equiv a^{\phi(b)}-1\equiv 0\mod b \\
E \equiv b^{\phi(a)}-1\equiv 0\mod a  
$$
therefore $E$ is a multiple of $a$ and a multiple of $b$ so it is a multiple of $ab$. But **I can't figure out** how to show that it is **equal** to $ab$ and not just a multiple.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150053/discussion-on-question-by-saitama10000-i-stumbled-across-an-identity-and-i-dont); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.